# At Schengen entry points, is a record kept of visa-free entry?

Tags: schengen

Travelling to Schengen border:

Do they record visa-free entries? Do they keep a record of your details?

Or do they just make a stamp in the passport without recording data?

Answer (score 4):

The entry and exit can be recorded in a national system but this is not — yet — a requirement and there is no system to exchange these data between Schengen countries. [A system to do just that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry/Exit_System) has been in the works for years and may become operational very soon (although the date has been postponed several times already).

By contrast, there are clear rules on stamps in the Schengen Borders Code and stamping is mandatory in most context but in practice these rules are not always followed by member states.